# Udp connection problem between esp8266 and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, udp, esp8266

I am trying to connect a Wemos D1 mini ESP8266 board to unity in order to send a button status to unity.

First I developed the code for the Wemos D1 mini and checked by using a UDP terminal and it worked fine I was sending a message from the terminal to the Wemos board and displaying the message on the serial monitor.

I was sending back a message with the button status and it was showing on the UDP terminal.

Then I wrote this code on Unity and attached it to the main camera and I am receiving the message sent by unity on the Wemos D1 mini but I cannot read the message Wemos is sending. I noticed that `Socket.Available` is always 0.

Apart from the fact that I am not reading the return message sometimes Unity is also crashing (not sometimes actually quite often when I run). This is the code from the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

//SSID of your network
char ssid[] = "TUI"; //SSID of your Wi-Fi router
char pass[] = "password"; //Password of your Wi-Fi router
int keyIndex = 0;

unsigned int localPort = 4000; 
char packetBuffer[255]; //buffer to hold incoming packet
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "";       // a string to send back

WiFiUDP Udp;

//input
const int buttonPin = 4;
const int ledpin = 5;
int buttonState = LOW;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
  IPAddress ip(192, 175, 0, 20); 
  IPAddress gateway(192, 175, 0, 1); 
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  IPAddress DNS(192, 175, 0, 1); 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet, DNS);  
  delay(100); 
  //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
  Serial.print("Connecting"); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("."); 
    delay(200);  
  }   
  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.println(); 
    Serial.println("Fail connecting"); 
    delay(5000); 
    ESP.restart(); 
  }   
  Serial.print("   OK  "); 
  Serial.print("Module IP: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  printWifiStatus(); 
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  Udp.begin(localPort);
} 

void loop () {// if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();

  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
    Serial.print(remoteIp);
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
    if (len > 0) {
      packetBuffer[len] = 0;
    }
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    String str(packetBuffer);

    if(str == "hello from unity"){
      digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH); 
    }

     buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
     if(buttonState == HIGH){
      String str1 = "Button1 pressed"; 
      str1.toCharArray(ReplyBuffer, 50); 
     }
     else{
      String str1 = "Button1 off"; 
      str1.toCharArray(ReplyBuffer, 50);
     }

     Serial.println(ReplyBuffer);
     Serial.println(Udp.remoteIP());
     Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent the packet
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
  else{
      digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);   
    }
    delay(10);
  }
```

This is the script on Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System;

public class ArduinoConnectUDP : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        udpSend();
    }

    //Port and IP Data for Socket Client
    void udpSend()
    {
        var IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.175.0.20"); 

        int port = 4000; 

        var udpClient1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        var sendEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);
        var receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        var clientReturn = new UdpClient(4000);

        try
        {
            //Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
            byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello from unity");

            udpClient1.SendTo(sendBytes, sendEndPoint);

            Debug.Log(udpClient1.Available);

            if (udpClient1.Available > 0)
            {
                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
               byte[] receiveBytes = clientReturn.Receive(ref receiveEndPoint);

                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                Debug.Log("Message Received: " +
                                    returnData.ToString());

                if (receiveBytes == null || receiveBytes.Length == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("No Answer from Wemos");
                }
            }
            udpClient1.Close();
            clientReturn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: i dont see error have you look at your firewall in case of....

Comment: No errors but I am not receiving the reply message in unity

Comment: if (udpClient1.Available > 0) - udpClient.Available is always resulting in 0 .... I created a rule in the firewall to allow everything on that port. But it wasn't the problem for sure since in the Udp terminal i am receiving from arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Had to change the receive code in c# and updated arduino code in order to send to port 4001 (static port since I was sending on the receive random port).

Code for Unity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class esp8266Connection : MonoBehaviour {

    Thread m_Thread;
    UdpClient m_Client;


    void Start()
    {
        m_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        m_Thread.IsBackground = true;
        m_Thread.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        udpSend();
    }

    void ReceiveData()
    {

        try
        {

            m_Client = new UdpClient(4001);
            m_Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
            while (true)
            {

                IPEndPoint hostIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] data = m_Client.Receive(ref hostIP);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

                Debug.Log(returnData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);

            OnApplicationQuit();
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (m_Thread != null)
        {
            m_Thread.Abort();
        }

        if (m_Client != null)
        {
            m_Client.Close();
        }
    }
    void udpSend()
    {
        var IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.175.0.20");

        int port = 4000;


        var udpClient1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        var sendEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);


        try
        {

            //Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
            byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello from unity");

            udpClient1.SendTo(sendBytes, sendEndPoint);



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Code for arduino:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

//SSID of your network
char ssid[] = "TUI"; //SSID of your Wi-Fi router
char pass[] = "password"; //Password of your Wi-Fi router
int keyIndex = 0;

unsigned int localPort = 4000; 
char packetBuffer[255]; //buffer to hold incoming packet
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "";       // a string to send back

WiFiUDP Udp;

//input
const int buttonPin = 4;
const int ledpin = D1;
int buttonState = LOW;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
  IPAddress ip(192, 175, 0, 20); 
  IPAddress gateway(192, 175, 0, 1); 
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  IPAddress DNS(192, 175, 0, 1); 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet, DNS);  
  delay(100); 
  //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
  Serial.print("Connecting"); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("."); 
    delay(200);  
  }   
  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.println(); 
    Serial.println("Fail connecting"); 
    delay(5000); 
    ESP.restart(); 
  }   
  Serial.print("   OK  "); 
  Serial.print("Module IP: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  printWifiStatus(); 
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  Udp.begin(localPort);
} 

void loop () {// if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();

  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
    Serial.print(remoteIp);
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
    if (len > 0) {
      packetBuffer[len] = 0;
    }
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    String str(packetBuffer);

    if(str == "hello from unity"){
      digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH); 
    }


     buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
     if(buttonState == HIGH){
      String str1 = "Button1 pressed"; 
      str1.toCharArray(ReplyBuffer, 50); 
     }
     else{
      String str1 = "Button1 off"; 
      str1.toCharArray(ReplyBuffer, 50);
     }

     Serial.println(ReplyBuffer);
      Serial.println(Udp.remoteIP());
      Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());


    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent the packet
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), 4001);
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }

  else{
      digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);   
    }
    delay(10);
  }

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```